# Rail Application having blogs with comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i am learning Ruby on Rails and i am using Rails 4. Following a Rails tutorial on Making a Blog App with Comments, the author wrote this to create a comment in comments_controller.rb

```
def create
@post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment=@post.comments.build(params[:post].permit[:body])
redirect_to @post_path(@post)
end
```

and in the partial : _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<h1><%= f.label :body %></h1><br />
<%= f.text_area :body %><br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I was wondering if i could only let the current user to comment on a post, having made all appropriate associations between User Model and Comment Model, so that while displaying the comments, i could retreive information from the User through Comment. Clearly, i do not just want to use a

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

as i want an association between User and Comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial you're following isn't so good.

---

Here's what you should be looking at:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :comments #-> url.com/posts/:post_id/comments/new
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @post.comments.new comment_params #-> notice the use of "strong params" (Google it)
      @post.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
   end
end
```

---

To add a `User` to a `Comment`, you'll want to do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :comments #-> url.com/posts/:post_id/comments/new
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user! #-> only if you're using devise

   def create
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @comment = current_user.comments.new comment_params
      @comment.post = @post
      @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
   end
end
```

If you're unsure about setting up a `has_many/belongs_to` relationship, you should create your tables [like this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have prepared proper associations between your models, and the question is how to update your controller's action to make it work.

If I have proper understanding of your `Comment` model, besides `post`, it has `body` and `user` attributes.

First of all, you should update your current code:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:post].permit[:body])
```

To look like this:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(body: params[:post].permit[:body])
```

To properly set the `body` attribute, and creating proper association with `current_user` is as simple as:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(body: params[:post].permit[:body],
  user: current_user)
```

At that point the comment is not saved yet, so you have two options:

1. After building the comment you can save it manually:

   @comment.save

Or 2. replace `build` with `create`:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(body: params[:post].permit[:body],
  user: current_user)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i tried it out Pawel, but i don't know why it doesn't seem to work. It just wont take more than one argument. We have got 2 here.